# Configure Wayland brightness control

Tags: arch-linux, wayland

On my Toshiba laptop I have two backlight devices in `/sys/class/backlight` called `toshiba` and `intel_backlight`. In Xorg, you could create a .conf file to choose which one the system should use. How do I do that in Wayland?

Comment: You don't. This is a great question to ask on the #wayland channel.

Comment: A little digging shows support is based on the display server implementation. For example, here's something related to [Weston](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199800/configure-wayland-brightness-control)

Comment: This long-standing issue with brightness control has been finally solved at it's source, the kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you don't "do it in Wayland," since Wayland is just a protocol.   It seems that configuring the backlight will need to be done based on either drm configuration and/or the particular display server config.

The details for Weston are in [the `backlight_init` function in *libbacklight.c*](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/cgit/?url=wayland/weston/tree/src/libbacklight.c).